# MySQL Composite PK with Nullable FKs

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys, data-modeling, nullable

First off, let me preface this question by stating that I'm really a pretty terrible data modeler.  I know only enough to be dangerous.

The table I'm building has four foreign keys, two of which reference the same table.  Here's the create statement for that table.

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `abnr`.`reputation_event_log` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `reputation_event_id` INT NULL ,
  `giver_user_id` INT NULL ,
  `receiver_user_id` INT NULL ,
  `review_id` INT NULL ,
  `giver_point_value` SMALLINT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `receiver_point_value` SMALLINT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_reputation_log_user` (`giver_user_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_reputation_log_user1` (`receiver_user_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_reputation_log_review` (`review_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_reputation_log_reputation_event` (`reputation_event_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_reputation_log_user`
    FOREIGN KEY (`giver_user_id` )
    REFERENCES `abnr`.`user` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_reputation_log_user1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`receiver_user_id` )
    REFERENCES `abnr`.`user` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_reputation_log_review`
    FOREIGN KEY (`review_id` )
    REFERENCES `abnr`.`review` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_reputation_log_reputation_event`
    FOREIGN KEY (`reputation_event_id` )
    REFERENCES `abnr`.`reputation_event` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

The indexes I'm concerned with for this post are `fk_reputation_log_user` and `fk_reputation_log_user1`.  Every reputation event has a giver, but only some have a receiver.  I would *like* this FK to be nullable, but I don't know how to do that, or if it's even "allowed".

I also toyed with the idea of making all FK columns part of the primary key to have database-level protection against duplicate log entries - but that won't work since PK columns have to be NOT NULL.

If you need more detail, please state that in the comments.  Thanks!

(Yes, this is for a reputation system not too dissimilar from what SO has)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `abnr`.`reputation_event_log` (
  `id`                  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `reputation_event_id` INT NULL ,
  `giver_user_id`       INT NOT NULL , -- mandatory giver_user_id
  `receiver_user_id`    INT NULL ,     -- optional receiver_user_id
  . . .
```

Yes, you can have `NULL` in a column with a foreign key constraint declared on it.  The `NOT NULL` constraint on a column is independent from any foreign key constraint(s) on that column.

A foreign key means that *if* the column has a non-NULL value, then that value must exist in the primary key of the table referenced by the foreign key constraint.

**edit:** As for your `UNIQUE` requirement, are you aware that you can declare a `UNIQUE` constraint on nullable columns.  The column *may* contain `NULL`s (unlike the primary key constraint).  This is standard SQL behavior, and is supported by MySQL.

```
  . . .
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (`giver_user_id`, `receiver_user_id`, 
                     `review_id`, `reputation_event_id`),
  . . .
```